# can not connect to wireless but can connect to office network

Tags: wireless-networking

My office desktop graphics card died. I put the hard drive into another byo computer that my son had been using at home. The desktop worked fine at home.  I checked all my settings.  I can connect to the office network, but not to the internet.  It is seen as an unidentified wire location although I have tried to change the   IPV 4 has no access.  I have reset the network adapter, rebooted the router, checked the status of my wireless card in device manager, checked ipconfig and did dns flush. I wasted 2 hours and ne ver got to do the paperwork I came in to do.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does your office use a proxy server? At home, when you are using your own network, you need to disable the proxy settings in your browser.